# Authorisation issues with app

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I am tryign to auth the users of my app by redirecting to this auth url

http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id={APP_ID}&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fapps.facebook.com%2F{APP_NAME}%2F&scope=email,user_about_me,user_birthday,user_hometown

It all works fine on my developer account that created the app and all authorises okay.

When I use another account that is not linked to the app in any way I am gettng the following error appearing but with no clue as to why?

[image: Error]

Does any one have any ideas as to why this may be happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that my Facebook App was corrupt in someway. I create a new app in Facebook with new APP ID and Secret and it all worked ok in the end.